# What size beam to I need for a 14ft sliding door opening in an exterior wall?

Tags: walls

I have a 2 level gable roof house with no basement. I want to replace a 6ft sliding door with a 14ft sliding door.

this particular wall has the 6ft door and a 72 in window, it is an exterior wall, the joists runs perpendicular to the wall and the wall also runs perpendicular to the roof peak.

the total width of the wall is 17.5 ft.

is this a load bearing wall? if it is, what size beam do I need to install?

Comment: What is the span of the perpendicular floor joists and perpendicular roof joists (trusses)? Do you use the attic? (I assume this is located on the first floor.) Do you have a perimeter foundation AND footing? What size?

Comment: So how much does the door weigh? Plus the fittings... that needs to be added to the loading as well as the dynamic loads...

Comment: @SolarMike Actually those are “static” loads. “Dynamic” loads are moving loads like on bridges...of which I know nothing about how to calculate those loads.

Comment: @LeeSam you did not read very well. I did not say the weight of the door was a dynamic load... I said that dynamic loads should be included as well for example the force of slamming the door or wind loading etc etc

Answer (score 1):

An exterior wall is almost certainly load bearing in any standard-design home structure. So yes, you will need to compensate for that if you are opening up a section of the wall.  Considering that you intend to have an opening (14') in a 17' wall, which comes to more than 80% of the wall's length, the beam is going to have to carry nearly the entire load, which makes it imperative that you get it sized and installed right.

As far as beam sizes...you really need to consult a structural engineer as there are many factors to consider and the last thing you want is for your changes to compromise the integrity of your structure.

Comment: I agree, it has been a long time but the last monster like that I used a compressed fiber beam, don’t remember the proper name but it was much smaller than all other wood type beams. And the engineer wanted that type or an I beam.

Comment: definately get an engineer on this one, the remaining  3" of wall will possibly need some fairly heroic reinforcement if that wall was a bracing wall.